# CIFilters to Show Clipped Highlights and Shadows

Tags: ios, swift, filter, cifilter, ciimage

In an image editing app, I am trying to show clipped highlights and shadows using CIFilters.

[image]

[Filter List](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html)

I know there isn't a straight single filter for this, will have to be a combination of few together.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

CIFilters can add one after another. for example: i can first adjust shadow on image and than crop it.

```
func addFilters(toImage image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else { return nil }
    let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

    //add adjust shadow filter
    guard let shadowAdjust = CIFilter(name: "CIHighlightShadowAdjust") else { return nil }
    shadowAdjust.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    shadowAdjust.setValue(1, forKey: "inputHighlightAmount")
    shadowAdjust.setValue(3, forKey: "inputShadowAmount")
    guard let output1 = shadowAdjust.outputImage else { return nil }

    //now output result crop 80%
    guard let crop = CIFilter(name: "CICrop") else { return nil }
    crop.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    crop.setValue(CIVector(x: output1.extent.origin.x, y: output1.extent.origin.y, z: output1.extent.size.width * 0.8, w: output1.extent.size.height * 0.8), forKey: "inputRectangle")
    guard let output2 = crop.outputImage else { return UIImage(ciImage: output1) }

    //the image will be croped and shadow adjusted
    return UIImage(ciImage: output2)
}
```

Comment: Understood.  I've stacked them in the past with good results.  Currently I am having trouble coming up the right combination of filters for showing blown highlights and shadows